How to Generate C# Client Code with Calculated Properties Using NSwag from OpenAPI Spec
I'm currently using NSwag to generate a C# client from an OpenAPI specification.
I have a particular case where I want a property in my C# model to be calculated based on other properties, similar to how you might use a read-only property in C#.
Here’s how this property looks in a typical C# class:
public string Id
{
    get
    {
        return Id1 + Id2 + Id3;
    }
}

The issue in trying to define this in an OpenAPI spec, I have not been able to generate code using NSwag which allows for this calculated value. The best I have been able to do is have a readonly propety, but I have not found any mechanism to have a calculated value.
I’ve explored using custom templates in NSwag but haven’t found a clear path to include properties that involve logic or calculation based on other fields.
Is there a recommended approach to handle properties like this when generating code with NSwag?
Can I somehow customize the generated code templates or use extensions in the OpenAPI spec to include calculated properties?
Any guidance, tips, or references to similar implementations would be highly appreciated!
13/05/2024 EDIT:
Still unsure, thank you

when I define this in an OpenAPI spec how do you do that? OpenAPI specifies the schema of the request and response payloads, not how they're implemented. Are you trying to "autogenerate" a request signature?

Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, sorry, I mean the challenge is somehow putting this autogenerated field into the contract (as it requires documentation for consumers), hope that clears it up a bit thanks
